# AnyConnect connection through VPN Settings

Tags: ios, vpn

I have an iPad with iOS 11.3. I have installed the Cisco AnyConnect app to connect to my companies VPNs. It connects to each of them fine. I can view the connection when connected in the Settings app under the VPN option. When I try and connect from the Settings app I am prompted that I must connect through the Cisco AnyConnect app rather than through the Settings app.

Is there a way to bypass that functionality so that the AnyConnect app will automatically open and prompt for my password when I activate VPN connections through the settings app?